# How can i print the Ping response?

Tags: jscript, wsh

How can i print or save in a var the Ping response?

```
var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
var oExec = WshShell.Exec("ping 127.0.0.1");
while (oExec.Status == 0)
{
     WScript.Sleep(100);
}

WScript.Echo(oExec.Status);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to save the result of the ping into a logfile in your drive, you can do it with this code:

```
var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
var oExec = WshShell.Exec("ping 127.0.0.1 > c:\pinglog.txt");
while (oExec.Status == 0)
{
     WScript.Sleep(100);
}

WScript.Echo(oExec.Status);
```

Comment: Now i have this code:

    var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    var oExec = WshShell.Exec("ping 127.0.0.1 > c:\Users\xps\pinglog.txt");

I have received error "expected hexadecimal number" 
I use CMD with Admin privilege.

Comment: if i put > c:\pinglog.txt doesn't happen nothing

Comment: You need to use double backslashes in JScript: `c:\\pinglog.txt`

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved as:

```
var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
var oExec = WshShell.Exec("cmd /c ping 127.0.0.1 > C:\\Users\\xps\\Desktop\\Pinglog.txt"   );


while (oExec.Status == 0)
{
     WScript.Sleep(100);
}

WScript.Echo(oExec.Status);
```